# Laravel 5.3 dd() output as plain text

Tags: php, debugging, curl, laravel-5

When I create a new, empty Collection in my Controller and `dd()` it, I get a nice result:

```
Collection {#205 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

But when I make a cURL call and `dd()` the Collection after that, the output is displayed in plain text (truncated):

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if ('sf-dump-compact' == oldClass) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if ('sf-dump-expanded' == oldClass) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = newClass; if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (a[s].className !== newClass) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; };
```

This is my code:

```
$collection = collect();
// dd( $collection );

header("Content-type: application/json");
$token
$url = "https://example.org";
$param= "authtoken=".$token;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

dd( $collection );
```

Does anyone know what's causing this? Could it have anything to do with the cURL call?

Comment: That's what the `dd` output actually looks like, what you see in your browser is the result of executing that script that it generates and its markup.

Comment: When I looked at the source code in both situations, I noticed that as well. But what I don't understand is why the result isn't formatted in the second situation, but all the code is visible on the page as plain text.

Comment: `header("Content-type: application/json");` is making the browser expect JSON instead of a webpage probably

Comment: That was the answer! Thank you very much.   

After removing that line, the output is properly formatted again. 
Could you submit it as answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with line:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

This will make the browser expect a JSON string as a response and will therefore not execute any scripts or render any HTML.

Removing this line will again format the result according to the output of `dd`